# listview filter with sql rawquery

Tags: android

Here's my problem: I need to execute a raw query sql with the text of the edit text user enter, and this consult be a filter in real time on list-view.
Sorry for my English.

```
editB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBuscar);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    editB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT nombre FROM recetas_tabla WHERE nombre = '"+editB.getText()+"' ", null);


            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                        names.add(cursor.getString(i));
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); {}


                    cursor.close();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
list.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will suggest to use autocompletetextview, fetch record just once and than this control will filter data as user enter

Comment: I'd replace `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT nombre FROM recetas_tabla WHERE nombre = '"+editB.getText()+"' ", null);
` with `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT nombre FROM recetas_tabla WHERE nombre Like '"+editB.getText().toString()+"%'", null);`. For your reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm
`

Comment: set a SimpleCursorAdapter to your lidt view and call adapter.getFilter().filter() in your TextWatcher, then setup a FilterQueryProvider on your adapter